# Is a strong reference cycle created in this simple case of using URLSession?

Tags: swift, automatic-ref-counting, urlsession, strong-reference-cycle

I'm a little confused about how strong references are created and when reference cycles occur. Here's a simple example:

```
class Model {
    var foo: Data?
    
    func makeRequest(url: URL) {
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            
            // assume request completes successfully
            self.foo = data!
        }

        task.resume()
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var model = Model()
    let url = URL(string: "abc.com")! // assume URL is valid
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        model.makeRequest(url: url)
    }
}
```

This is my understanding of how the references work in the code above:

1. The variable `model` holds a strong reference to an instance of the Model class
2. URLSession holds a strong reference to its data task, which holds a strong reference to the closure.
3. The closure escapes the function, and because it needs to update self, it holds a strong reference to the Model instance
4. However, the Model instance does not hold a strong reference to the data task and therefore there is no reference cycle.

Is this correct? And if so, I really don't understand step 4. Why doesn't the Model instance hold a strong reference to the data task, since the task is created in a function of the Model class?

Note: I've seen several related questions, but I still don't understand why the Model instance does not hold a strong reference back to the session, task, or closure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a cycle here (as you note). However, `URLSession.shared`, which never goes away, does hold a reference to the task, which holds a reference to `Model`. This means that `Model` cannot deallocate until the task completes. (If `Model` had a `urlSession` property, then there technically would be a loop, but it wouldn't change anything in practice. "Loops" are not magical. If something that lives forever holds a reference to something, it will keep that object alive forever.)

This is generally a good thing. URLSession tasks automatically release their completion block when they finish, so `Model` is only kept alive until the task is done. As long as `Model` doesn't assume that `ViewController` still exists (which it shouldn't), there is nothing wrong here as far as reference cycles.

The one thing that is kind of bad about this code is that `Model` doesn't hold onto the task so it can cancel it, or even detect that one is in progress (to avoid making duplicate requests in parallel). That's not a major problem for simple apps, but is something that is useful to improve in more complex apps.

Answer (score 2):

Let’s go through your questions one at a time:

> This is my understanding of how the references work in the code above:
>
> 1. The variable `model` holds a strong reference to an instance of the `Model` class.

Correct, the view controller keeps that strong reference until the view controller, itself, is deallocated.

> 2. `URLSession` holds a strong reference to its data task, which holds a strong reference to the closure.

The `URLSession` maintains this strong reference until the request finishes/fails, at which point the data task is released. You do not need to keep a reference to the data task, as `URLSession` automatically hangs on to it for the duration of the request anyway. That having been said, we often would keep our own `weak` reference to it, which we would use if/when we might want to cancel the request. (See below.)

> 3. The closure escapes the function, and because it needs to update self, it holds a strong reference to the Model instance

Yes, as it stands, the closure maintains a strong reference to `self`, and this closure will not be released until the data task finishes or fails.

As an aside, we generally would not do that. Often we would use a `[weak self]` capture list in this closure, so that it does not keep this strong reference to `self`. E.g., you might:

```swift
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { [weak self] data, response, error in
    // see if `self` was released
    guard let self else { return }

    // see if request succeeded
    guard let data else {
        print(error ?? URLError(.badServerResponse))
        return
    }

    // if we got here, we have our `Data`; we always avoid forced unwrapping operators when dealing with data from a remote server
    self.foo = data
}
```

> 4. However, the `Model` instance does not hold a strong reference to the data task and therefore there is no reference cycle.

Yes. Or more accurately, as implemented in the question, the `URLSession` will keep a strong reference to `self`, will release that strong reference when the request finishes or fails. But, again, if we use `[weak self]` capture list as outlined above, it won’t keep a strong reference at all, and the `Model` will be deallocated as soon as the view controller is deallocated.

---

Even better, unless we explicitly need the task to continue running even if the `Model` is deallocated for some reason, we would `cancel` the `task` when `Model` is deallocated:

```swift
class Model {
    var foo: Data?
    private weak var task: URLSessionTask?

    deinit {
        task?.cancel()
    }
    
    func makeRequest(url: URL) {
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { [weak self] data, response, error in
            guard let self else { return }
        
            guard let data else {
                print(error ?? URLError(.badServerResponse))
                return
            }
        
            self.foo = data
        }

        task.resume()
        self.task = task
    }
}
```

Note, we neither need nor want to keep a strong reference to the `URLSessionTask`. (The `URLSession` will manage the lifecycle of the `URLSessionTask`.) But we keep our own `weak` reference, which will automatically be set to `nil` when the `URLSessionTask` is done. That way, if the request is not yet done when `Model` is deallocated, we can cancel the request. But if the request is already done, that `task` reference will be set to `nil` automatically for us, in which case the `task?.cancel()`, becomes a “no op”.

Comment: Needless to say, Rob Napier’s answer is correct (+1) and should be the accepted answer. I just wanted to add a few clarifications…